# android layout problem with image length

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an image of a line and I want it to go from end to end (left to right). However thats not happening ! And I am not sure why - I have used fill_parent as the width. Any help ?

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/twsep1"
android:src="@drawable/separator" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/twedit11"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

screenshot:

[image]

full layout:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/backgroundnr"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="5dp"
              android:paddingTop="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp">


            <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/twicon" 
            android:layout_height="90px"
            android:layout_width="120px"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView 
            android:text="I like:" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/twlabel1"
            android:textSize="18px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twicon"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/twedit11"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="18px"
                android:layout_below="@+id/twlabel1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twicon"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" 
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            </EditText>


            <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/twsep1"
            android:src="@drawable/separator" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/twedit11"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView 
            android:text="Write a comment:" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/twlabel3"
            android:textSize="18px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/twsep1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            </TextView>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/twedit22"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="18px"
                android:layout_below="@+id/twlabel3"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            </EditText>


            <TextView 
            android:text="Press TWEET to publish." 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/twlabel5"
            android:textSize="18px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/twedit22"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            </TextView>

            <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/twsep2" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/separator"
            android:layout_below="@+id/twlabel5"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            </ImageView>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/twButton"
            android:text="Tweet"
            android:background="@drawable/ebutton"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/twsep2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            </Button>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you have it include into another layout (maybe programmable one) . For example a tabHost .

Show us the java class you use to inflate it , I think the clue is there .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ....

```
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
```

?

Comment: its way to smaller than a padding of 5 on both sides!

Answer (score 1):

you have used both

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

try after removing both the above. If you still face problem then specify what exactly are you getting or if possible attach a screen shot.

Comment: added full layout @Vineet Shukla

Comment: you mean the image thats being short ? So you are saying that the image needs to be longer (have more width) ? or what ?

Comment: I am not sure as the code is working fine at my end... the image should stretch as you have used fill_parent...you need to debug what is the problem...

Answer (score 1):

With your width set to fill_parent you do not need:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

This may be causing a weird issue, but also you do not need these lines either because they will cause padding to each side.

```
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
```

With a more complete layout posted we can give you a better answer.

Comment: i did try the align lines - didnt help :(

Comment: Can you post the full layout please?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType). I think what you need is fitXY.
Just add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your ImageView.

I would also look into [NinePatches](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you could post code for it's parent layout, it could be of some help.

What about it's parent Layout, how have you mapped it, is the parent's width "wrap_content" or a "value" or "fill_parent" or what? may  be this image's immediate parent may himself be contained w.r.t his parent or his width parameter. Jus check it out.

Comment: well Ahsan, try removing the padding:Left & padding:Right from its parent, that is from RelativeLayout. may be that is causing this image's width not to extend till its parent's actual end.